paho mqtt in python3: no module named typing_extensions
Pi Zero W Rev 1.1, running raspian buster.
I can't seem to import the paho MQTT client in python 3, with the error shown below.
Here are my installation steps:
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt install python3-pip
sudo pip3 install paho-mqtt
env PYTHONPATH='/home/mpi'
sudo env PYTHONPATH='/home/mpi'


in python3 from the console:
>>> import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/paho/mqtt/client.py", line 49, in <module>
    from typing import Literal
ImportError: cannot import name 'Literal' from 'typing' (/usr/lib/python3.7/typing.py)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/paho/mqtt/client.py", line 51, in <module>
    from typing_extensions import Literal  # type: ignore
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'typing_extensions'



I get the same error when I try to import paho in a script. I tried
sudo pip3 install typing_extensions

to no avail. Are there any workarounds, or does anyone have a solution?

Since paho-mqtt requires Python 3.8+ for Literal, it might be helpful to use an older version compatible with Python 3.7. Install paho-mqtt==1.5.1, which doesn’t rely on Literal and is compatible with Python 3.7:
sudo pip3 install paho-mqtt==1.5.1

That would explain why I've not had this happen before... thx

Kind of weird the default package would be incompatible with the system python.  If someone has time to type this out as an actual answer, please do.

I over-installed paho-mqtt 1.5.1 but have the same error - is there a method to remove python3 altogether and all the libraries, and start over? I'll flash another micro SD if need be.

If you're willing to reflash the card, start with a new image, current python on bookworm is 3.11.2; I have Pi's running that and bullseye (python 3.9.2) that use paho.mqtt.client with no problems (admittedly in a venv, but those are derived from the system python).

Buster was released in 2019, so if you have the opportunity, I would recommend updating to the current version - currently it is Bookworm (based on Debian 12).
In this case, by update I mean a clean installation from scratch.
After that, repeat your installation steps.
Or install a newer Python 3.8+ from source.
Literal was supported in Python 3.8, and you are using 3.7
Python Release Schedule:

3.7 (27 Jun 2018)
3.8 (14 Oct 2019)


reflashing and installing libraries all at once was the answer - I updated to python3 and did not start with MQTT until long after that.  Thanks to all who took the time to answer.
